# Survey of Quantum Algorithms similar to Montanaro's from 2015

Tags: ds.algorithms, quantum-computing

The survey https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04206 by Montanaro is very nice in terms of giving a bird's eye view, which is very useful. As the author states in the abstract

> Here we briefly survey some known quantum algorithms, with an emphasis on a broad overview of their applications rather than their technical details. We include a discussion of recent developments and near-term applications of quantum algorithms.

That survey is now 7 years old and the field has changed. Not being an expert but just an interested outsider, I was wondering if there is a more up to date survey with similar scope and detail.

**Edit:**

Here are three more recent surveys I found, only the first one is general.

Quantum Computing 2022, by James D. Whitfield et al
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.09877.pdf

> [We aim to] provide a sober assessment of the promise of quantum
> technology with a focus on computing. We provide a tour of
> quantum computing and quantum technology that is aimed to
> be comprehensible to scientists and engineers without becoming
> a popular account. The goal is not a comprehensive review nor
> a superficial introduction but rather to serve as a useful map to
> navigate the hype, the scientific literature, and upcoming press
> releases about quantum technology and quantum computing.

Ciliberto C, et al.
Quantum machine learning: a
classical perspective. Proceedings of the Royal Society A, 2018.

https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.2017.0551

> Here we review the literature in quantum
> ML and discuss perspectives for a mixed readership
> of classical ML and quantum computation experts.
> Particular emphasis will be placed on clarifying
> the limitations of quantum algorithms, how they
> compare with their best classical counterparts and
> why quantum resources are expected to provide
> advantages for learning problems

Laszlo Gyongyosi, Sandor Imre, A Survey on quantum computing technology,
*Computer Science Review*, 2019.

https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cosrev.2018.11.002

> The power of quantum computing technologies is based on the fundamentals of quantum mechanics,
> such as quantum superposition, quantum entanglement, or the no-cloning theorem. Since
> these phenomena have no classical analogue, similar results cannot be achieved within
> the framework of traditional computing. The experimental insights of quantum computing
> technologies have already been demonstrated, and several studies are in progress.
> Here we review the most recent results of quantum computation technology and
> address the open problems of the field.

I would appreciate any comments on these references and any suggestions of more surveys to look at.

Comment: Have you tried looking at all more recent papers that cite it, using e.g. Google Scholar?

Comment: Do you know about the [Quantum Algorithm Zoo](https://quantumalgorithmzoo.org/)? I believe it's actively maintained, the last update was on February 1, 2021.